# How to replace a lines by specified lines which has specific pattern?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, replace

I have a text file like below:

```
geo.txt

Receptor Name:I151T.B99990002_mus.pdbqt
Liang Name: LIGAND 1
Using random seed: 1896818552

mode |   affinity | dist from best mode
     | (kcal/mol) | rmsd l.b.| rmsd u.b.
-----+------------+----------+----------
     1        -10.7      0.000      0.000
     2        -10.4      1.859      3.037
     3        -10.1      1.992      3.474

Receptor Name: I151T.B99990001_mus.pdbqt
Liang Name: LIGAND 1
Using random seed: 1896818552

mode |   affinity | dist from best mode
     | (kcal/mol) | rmsd l.b.| rmsd u.b.
-----+------------+----------+----------
     1         -9.5      0.000      0.000
     2         -9.4      2.083      3.784
     3         -9.0      2.471      8.360
     4         -9.0      1.493      3.523
```

In the above file,I want to extract each lines which has a pattern (Receptor Name:) and add those lines with their corresponding values.

What I have tried:

```
import  os
import re

h=open("/Users/geoList.txt","r")
for i in h:
    if re.match(r'\s\s\s\d+', i) or i.startswith("Receptor Name:"):
        print i.replace("\n","")
```

I got output like below:

```
Receptor Name: I151T.B99990002_mus.pdbqt
   1        -10.7      0.000      0.000
   2        -10.4      1.859      3.037
   3        -10.1      1.992      3.474

Receptor Name:I151T.B99990001_mus.pdbqt
   1         -9.5      0.000      0.000
   2         -9.4      2.083      3.784
   3         -9.0      2.471      8.360
   4         -9.0      1.493      3.523
```

But here, I dont know how to connect lines which has (Receptor Name:) with their respective values.

For example: the expected output file should be like below:

```
FIRST PATTERN MATCH: with corresponding values:
-----------------------------------------------

Receptor Name:I151T.B99990002_mus.pdbqt 1        -10.7      0.000      0.000

Receptor Name:I151T.B99990002_mus.pdbqt 2        -10.4      1.859      3.037

Receptor Name:I151T.B99990002_mus.pdbqt 3        -10.1      1.992      3.474

SECOND PATTERN MATCH: with corresponding values
-----------------------------------------------

Receptor Name: I151T.B99990001_mus.pdbqt 1         -9.5      0.000      0.000

Receptor Name: I151T.B99990001_mus.pdbqt 2         -9.4      2.083      3.784

Receptor Name: I151T.B99990001_mus.pdbqt 3         -9.0      2.471      8.360

Receptor Name: I151T.B99990001_mus.pdbqt 4         -9.0      1.493      3.523
```

Thanks in advnce

Comment: This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Dear  jonrsharpe, Many thanks for reply. I have added what I have tried where I just want to join each header filenames (Receptor name:) with their corresponding values. So if you know how to do this could you help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this (you only need to store the line with "Receptor"):

```
>>> for line in h:
...     if line.startswith('Receptor Name:'):
...         prefix = line
...     elif re.search(r'^\s+\d', line):
...         print prefix + ' ' + line.strip()
```

Comment: for line in h:
    if line.startswith('Receptor Name:'):
        prefix=line
    elif re.search(r'^\s+\d', line):
        print prefix.strip()+line

Comment: it works as I expected in simple logic Thank you somuch

Answer (score 1):

You can do this entirely with a regex:

```
/(^Receptor Name:[^\n]*)(?:.*?^[-+]+)(.*?)(?=^Receptor Name:|\Z)/\1\2/gms
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aM0iD2/2)

Which is then easily rolled into Python logic to do what you want:

```
txt='''\
Receptor Name:I151T.B99990002_mus.pdbqt
Liang Name: LIGAND 1
Using random seed: 1896818552

mode |   affinity | dist from best mode
     | (kcal/mol) | rmsd l.b.| rmsd u.b.
-----+------------+----------+----------
     1        -10.7      0.000      0.000
     2        -10.4      1.859      3.037
     3        -10.1      1.992      3.474

Receptor Name: I151T.B99990001_mus.pdbqt
Liang Name: LIGAND 1
Using random seed: 1896818552

mode |   affinity | dist from best mode
     | (kcal/mol) | rmsd l.b.| rmsd u.b.
-----+------------+----------+----------
     1         -9.5      0.000      0.000
     2         -9.4      2.083      3.784
     3         -9.0      2.471      8.360
     4         -9.0      1.493      3.523'''

import re
pat=re.compile(r'(^Receptor Name:[^\n]*)(?:.*?^[-+]+)(.*?)(?=^Receptor Name:|\Z)', flags=re.S | re.M)   

for m in pat.finditer(txt):
    for line in m.group(2).splitlines():
        line=line.strip()
        if line:
             print m.group(1), line
```

Prints:

```
Receptor Name:I151T.B99990002_mus.pdbqt 1        -10.7      0.000      0.000
Receptor Name:I151T.B99990002_mus.pdbqt 2        -10.4      1.859      3.037
Receptor Name:I151T.B99990002_mus.pdbqt 3        -10.1      1.992      3.474
Receptor Name: I151T.B99990001_mus.pdbqt 1         -9.5      0.000      0.000
Receptor Name: I151T.B99990001_mus.pdbqt 2         -9.4      2.083      3.784
Receptor Name: I151T.B99990001_mus.pdbqt 3         -9.0      2.471      8.360
Receptor Name: I151T.B99990001_mus.pdbqt 4         -9.0      1.493      3.523
```

Comment: This is exactly what I expected thank you somuch. if you hve no issue could you explain me the code it would be nice for future